# ORDER BY RAND() always gives same row on IE

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I have a javascript function(called by a button) which does an ajax request to a php file. 
The php file connects to the database and echo(es) me a random row from my database. The php code responsible for this:

```
$value = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
echo $value;
```

Everything works fine! On all browsers(except IE), I can press the button and get randow row each time. However on IE it gives me the same row until I refresh the page. 
I tried on all versions of IE, the row doesnot change until I refresh the page.

Any idea what it could be?

Thanks in advance!

Here are more codes:

```
function getdata(){
    var data = $.ajax({
            url: "getmydata.php",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

    passdata(data); 
}
```

Edit: I know ORDER BY RAND is bad, but I only have 10 rows!

Comment: why the `async: false`?

Comment: It's probably cached on the client. SQL queries aren't affected by the user agent.

Comment: @GNi33: Correct me if I am wrong? Synchronous requests can lock up the ajax state and browser.

Comment: @alex: I tried on IE of Windows phone to IE on vmware. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: @NabRaj You are right. Which makes the `async: false` confusing :)

Comment: @NabRaj exactly, this function will block until the Ajax-call is completed, consider using a callback - function instead. As to your problem, have you tried adding a changing parameter to your call? like `data: {'cacheParam' : Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, IE is notorious for aggressively caching requests and ignoring HTTP headers to not cache content.  In our applications, when we have an AJAX request that *must* be refreshed from the server, we use a cache busting random number in the url:

```
url: "getmydata.php?rand="+Math.random()
```

The `?` is used to add [querystring parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), which will have no effect on the request if you don't process them. Since the url is unique every time, it can never be cached.

---

**Edit**: As pointed out by @GNi33, there is already a feature built into [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to force cache  busting with a parameter called `cache` set to `false`:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    url: "getmydata.php",
    cache: false,    /* ADD THIS to prevent IE caching */
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

Either of these solutions is sufficient.

Comment: my thougts too, just remembered that this is even built in in the jQuery `.ajax` - function, using the `cache` - property and setting it to `false`

Comment: Thanks mellamokb and GNi3, that worked! I added both Math.random() and cache: false on the request. Cheers!

Comment: @NabRaj: Note that applying both of those solutions is overkill, because they are both equally sufficient.

Comment: @NabRaj there's no need to set them both, just using `cache:false` should suffice perfectly :) because behind the scenes, jQuery is doing  nothing else than setting a parameter like that

Comment: Thanks again, removed Math.random(). I like cache:false better! Cheers!